# Gradle: Shared java project with an android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got this shared common classes that I extracted into a separate "common" module with gradle (which has dependencies on some jars). I defined it as a java project because I want to also use it outside of the android context. But when I include it in my android project with:

```
compile project(':my_common')
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what is your project structure? have you added this to `settings.gradle`?

Comment: I included all of my subprojects in the root project.

Comment: please post build.gradle